# unable to perform CURD operations on hbase even the hbase master and region server is up and running

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to run my hbase master from ambari and it has been started....even I used JPS command to see whether master is up or not and I can see that it is up but then also when I am trying to create table or listing table it is showing the exception.....

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FifoRpcScheduler$1.run(FifoRpcScheduler.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I used JPS command it is showing like this....

```
[root@sandbox data]# jps

1763 SecondaryNameNode
26608 HRegionServer
12869 DataNode
24772 HMaster
```

while I am trying to List the tables in Hbase it is showing the folowing exception.....

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FifoRpcScheduler$1.run(FifoRpcScheduler.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here is some help for this command:
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:



hbase> list
hbase> list 'abc.*'
 hbase> list 'ns:abc.*'
hbase> list 'ns:.*'
```

This is my hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
  <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
  <value>10485760</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
  <value>100</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
  <value>com.xasecure.authorization.hbase.XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
  <value>com.xasecure.authorization.hbase.XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction</name>
  <value>604800000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction.jitter</name>
  <value>0.50</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
  <value>10737418240</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.block.multiplier</name>
  <value>4</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size</name>
  <value>134217728</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.mslab.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles</name>
  <value>10</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hstore.compactionThreshold</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.local.dir</name>
  <value>${hbase.tmp.dir}/local</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
  <value>60010</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.port</name>
  <value>60000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.lowerLimit</name>
  <value>0.38</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit</name>
  <value>0.4</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
  <value>60</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.info.port</name>
  <value>60030</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/hbase/data</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.engine</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SecureRpcEngine</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.protection</name>
  <value>PRIVACY</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
  <value>simple</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.superuser</name>
  <value>hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/hadoop/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2181</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.useMulti</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase_master_heapsize</name>
  <value>250</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase_regionserver_heapsize</name>
  <value>250</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hfile.block.cache.size</name>
  <value>0.40</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
  <value>30000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
  <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
</property>
```

Comment: could you post your hbase-site.xml?

Comment: ok yosr...I had posted my hbase-site.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit you `hbase-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
</property> 

<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>  
   <value>localhost</value>
</property>

<property>   
  <name>dfs.replication</name>   
  <value>1</value>    
</property>

 <property>       
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>  
  <value>2181</value>                                                                                 
 </property>

 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hbase/zookeeper</value>   
 </property>
```

Comment: hi yosr thanks for answering but I had tried changing my hbase-site.xml but it is not solving the issue still I am recieving the same exception.....is their any other way to solve this????

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: no it should appear because hbase works on the top of hdfs so namenode should be up otherwise it will not get started...

Comment: so that's the problem your namenode should be up